# Selective suppression of output to the terminal C++.

Tags: c++, terminal, argc

I have a bunch of `.cpp` files which together process similar data files but of various sizes. For the larger data files I want to do some timing studies on the functions inside the .cpp files.

I would like to suppress the output the results for these big data sets, and only print the timing results. For smaller data sets, I would like to print to the screen  to verify algorithm/code correctness.

Rather than repeatedly commenting/uncommenting out the appropriate `cout` statements and recompiling ,  I would like to use command line arguments (or some other technique) to selectively suppress output.

Any suggestions? The naive one I can think of is use `argc` and `argv`, but I am not sure if they are global variables which can be used by functions across different files.

Comment: You realise that suppressing output will change how fast your program runs?

Comment: I have separated the comptuation of a result from the printing of the result. Thus timing will not be affected. Thus I can just time the computation which will not change if I suppress the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct -- use the `argc` and `argv` values passed into your `main` function -- but they are not global variables.  You need to make your information global somehow: I'd recommend parsing the arguments once, and keeping a set of global flags that can easily be queried.

For example:

```
// In a common header file that gets included in each source file
extern bool g_bFlag1;
extern bool g_bFlag2;
...

// In your main source file
bool g_bFlag1 = false;
bool g_bFlag2 = false;
...
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Parse command line and store results in global flags
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "--flag1") == 0)
            g_bFlag1 = true;
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "--flag2") == 0)
            g_bFlag2 = true;
        else
            ;  // etc.
    }
}

// In any other source file:
if (g_bFlag1)
{
    // do stuff if and only if g_bFlag1 is set
}
```

Then you can pass `--flag1` on the command line.  For more complicated argument parsing, I'd suggest using a library such as [GNU getopt](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Getopt.html).

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution! I will use this.

Answer (score 4):

Of course `argv` and `argc` are **not** global variables, as they are patently function-scope local variables of `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

For convenient option processing, you might like to look at `getopt.h`.

One way to suppress output would be to use `grep` or file redirection on the shell (`time ./prog > /dev/null`), but that still incurs the cost of the actual output functions.

I suggest two possible ideas:

1. Surround your critical functions by calls to `clock()` and do the measuring and reporting yourself.
2. Allow the user to pass a verbosity parameter (either at runtime with a command-line option, or at compile time with a `#define`) and only print depending on the verbosity level.

For idea (1) I use the following macros:

```
#define CLOCK_TICK(acc, ctr)  ctr = std::clock()
#define CLOCK_TOCK(acc, ctr)  acc += (std::clock() - ctr)
#define CLOCK_RESET(acc) acc = 0
#define CLOCK_REPORT(acc) 1000. * double(acc) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
```

For idea (2), I'd do something like this:

```
#ifndef VERBOSE
#  define VERBOSE 0
#endif

#if VERBOSE > 0
// print level 1
#if VERBOSE > 1
// print level 2
#endif
#endif
```

Then you can compile with `-DVERBOSE=3` etc. to enable logging at a specific level.

If this is too manual, you should look into a proper logging framework for your application.

Comment: The macros ideas was quite useful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By default, all you've got to work with for output are stdout (as `cout`) and stderr (as `cerr`).

So some options are:

- write your timing to stderr, instead of stdout, and pipe them to different places at the command line
- open a logfile for your timing data, and write to that
- tag each line of your output with something like "[timing]", then use `grep` on the command line to only show the output lines you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use preprocessor directive to do that:

```
/*inside file_name.cpp*/

//uncomment next line to activate debug print on this file
//#define FILE_NAME_DEBUG  
#ifdef FILE_NAME_DEBUG
cout << "activate debug print\n";
#endif
```

This approach can selectively suppress the print statement but require to recompile the module each time.

Comment: This will require compile again

Comment: @robermorales: yes but has the advantage that the code inside the ifdef can be 1)excluded from the compilation itself 2)easy to remove